# Add custom columns to delayed_jobs table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Can someone show me how to extend the delayed_jobs gem to allow me to add a couple custom columns?

I added a couple columns but when I try to 'cleanly' use them I get:

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: owner_type, owner_id

So I need to add the columns to cattr_accessor:

```
module Delayed
  class Worker
    DEFAULT_SLEEP_DELAY      = 5
    DEFAULT_MAX_ATTEMPTS     = 25
    DEFAULT_MAX_RUN_TIME     = 4.hours
    DEFAULT_DEFAULT_PRIORITY = 0
    DEFAULT_DELAY_JOBS       = true
    DEFAULT_QUEUES           = []
    DEFAULT_READ_AHEAD       = 5

    cattr_accessor :min_priority, :max_priority, :max_attempts, :max_run_time,
      :default_priority, :sleep_delay, :logger, :delay_jobs, :queues,
      :read_ahead, :plugins, :destroy_failed_jobs, **:owner_id, :owner_type**
```

However, not sure the best way to extend this.  My guess/attempt is to create a file and add it to the initializers directory.  However, for some reason it didn't work.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to extend the delayed_jobs table?  My approach has been to leave it alone and use one of two techniques:

- add owner_id and owner_type fields the the object being queued.
- create a separate table with a :belongs_to relationship to delayed_jobs.  Then you use DJ's hooks to keep the two in synch through the lifetime of the job.

The first approach is simpler, but isn't right for every situation.  Would either of those work for you?

Comment: I may go this route - but the other devs have added columns already.  I would like to access those columns via delay(:owner_id => etc...).  Otherwise I have to create an instance of DJ and assign the values as I would any other object.  That's fine, but adding a dash of code to the gem would make this a one-liner vs. 2,3,4...

Comment: "Otherwise I have to create an instance of DJ and assign the values as I would any other object." -- not sure I understand that statement.  If you already have a custom delay-able object (one that implements #perform), then you can add your :owner_id and :owner_type fields to it with no extra effort, no?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers may be useful, but they are not answering the question. To add custom columns to the `delayed_jobs` table, you can follow [this steps](http://sunilkumarn.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/delayed-jobs-in-rails-adding-custom-attributes/). I did so and successfully created an association between `Delayed::Job` and other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply add the following line in your initializer (ex. config/initializers/delayed_job.rb):

```
Delayed::Job.attr_accessible :owner_type, :owner_id
```